# Replace url premeters to path based prameter

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have the following controller which accepts an optional "page" parameter.

Right now my URL would look something like mysite.com/pittsburgh-listings?page=2

I want the urls to look like this instead, how can I achieve this?

```
mysite.com/pittsburgh-listings/2
mysite.com/pittsburgh-listings/3
etc..
```

My controller

```
@Controller
public class CityController {
    private static final int BUTTONS_TO_SHOW = 5;
    private static final int INITIAL_PAGE = 0;
    private static final int INITIAL_PAGE_SIZE = 40;
    private static final int[] PAGE_SIZES = { 5, 10, 20, 40 };

    private AdService adService;

    public CityController(AdService adService) {
        this.adService = adService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{city:[\\w'-]+}-listings", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String city(@PathVariable("city") String city, Model model, @RequestParam("page") Optional<Integer> page) {
        Database db = new Database();
        model.addAttribute("city", city.replace("-", " "));
        System.out.println(city.replace("-", " "));

        // List<Ad> ads = adService.getPage(1, city.replace("-", " "));
        // model.addAttribute("ads", ads);

        int evalPageSize = INITIAL_PAGE_SIZE;
        int evalPage = (page.orElse(0) < 1) ? INITIAL_PAGE : page.get() - 1;
        Long cityId = null;
        try {
            cityId = db.getCityId(city.replace("-", " "));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Page<Ad> ads = adService.findAllPageable(new PageRequest(evalPage, evalPageSize, Sort.Direction.DESC, "id"),
                cityId);
        System.out.println("Ads: " + ads.getSize());
        Pager pager = new Pager(ads.getTotalPages(), ads.getNumber(), BUTTONS_TO_SHOW);

        model.addAttribute("ads", ads);
        model.addAttribute("selectedPageSize", evalPageSize);
        model.addAttribute("pageSizes", PAGE_SIZES);
        model.addAttribute("pager", pager);
        return "city";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change method signature as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/{city:[\\w'-]+}-listings", "/{city:[\\w'-]+}-listings/{page}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String city(@PathVariable("city") String city, @PathVariable Optional<Integer> page, Model model) {
   // ...
}
```

In order to map two endpoints (with and without page) in the same controller method and using Java 8 Optional to get page value.

Comment: In my Thymeleaf template I have `th:href="${page}" ` for the page link and it generates, something like mydomain.com/2 how can I make it also include the path of the page I'm already on? for example mydomain.com/pittsburgh-listings/2